# i want to implement map in c++ , for that i can't check vector size and give values to vector i made

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, templates, vector

i made two classes `Node` and `Map` , when i try to get `table_size` in `Map Constructor` and want assign all vector values as `nullptr` it gives me error.

my code is here **it's not a problem by overloaded operator i commented it , i still get error**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T1,class T2>
class Node {
    public:
        T1 key;
        T2 value;
        Node* next;

    Node(T1 key,T2 value) : key(key) , value(value) , next(nullptr) {};
};

template <class T1,class T2>
class Map {
    private:
        std::vector<Node<T1,T2>*> hash_table[117];
        int table_size;
    public:
        Map() {
            table_size = hash_table.size();
            for(int i=0;i<table_size;i++) {
                hash_table[i] = nullptr;
            }
        }

        // i assumed that T1 is always string
        int stringToHash(T1 key) {
            int num = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<key.length();i++) {
                num += int(key[i]);
            }
            return ( ( num * 1027 ) % table_size );
        }

        void put(T1 key,T2 value) {
            int idx = stringToHash(key);
            Node<T1,T2>* new_node = createNode(key,value);

            if(hash_table[idx] == nullptr)
                hash_table[idx] = new_node;
            else {
                Node<T1,T2>* ptr = hash_table[idx];
                while(ptr->next != nullptr) {
                    ptr = ptr->next;
                }
                ptr->next = new_node;
            }
        }

        T2 operator[] (T1 key) {
            int idx = stringToHash(key);
            Node<T1,T2>* ptr = hash_table[idx];

            T2 value;
            while(ptr != nullptr) {
                if(ptr->key == key) {
                    value = ptr->value;
                }
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }

            return value;
        }

        Node<T1,T2>* createNode(T1 key,T2 value) {
            Node<T1,T2>* new_node = new Node<T1,T2>(key,value);
            return new_node;
        }
};

int main() {

    Map<std::string,std::string> arr;
    return 0;
}
```

my error follows as

```
03_map.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Map<T1, T2>::Map() [with T1 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; T2 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
03_map.cpp:74:34:   required from here
03_map.cpp:21:37: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘((Map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*)this)->Map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::hash_table’, which is of non-class type ‘std::vector<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*, std::allocator<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*> > [117]’
   21 |             table_size = hash_table.size();
      |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
03_map.cpp:23:31: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*, std::allocator<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*> >’ and ‘std::nullptr_t’)
   23 |                 hash_table[i] = nullptr;
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/vector:72,
                 from 03_map.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/vector.tcc:198:5: note: candidate: ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _Alloc = std::allocator<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*>]’
  198 |     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/vector.tcc:199:42: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::nullptr_t’ to ‘const std::vector<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*, std::allocator<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*> >&’
  199 |     operator=(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x)
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/vector:67,
                 from 03_map.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:709:7: note: candidate: ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&&) [with _Tp = Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _Alloc = std::allocator<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*>]’
  709 |       operator=(vector&& __x) noexcept(_Alloc_traits::_S_nothrow_move())
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:709:26: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::nullptr_t’ to ‘std::vector<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*, std::allocator<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*> >&&’
  709 |       operator=(vector&& __x) noexcept(_Alloc_traits::_S_nothrow_move())
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:730:7: note: candidate: ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::initializer_list<_Tp>) [with _Tp = Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*; _Alloc = std::allocator<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*>]’
  730 |       operator=(initializer_list<value_type> __l)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:730:46: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::nullptr_t’ to ‘std::initializer_list<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*>’
  730 |       operator=(initializer_list<value_type> __l)
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

can you tell me what did i done wrong ?

Comment: `hash_table` is an array. It has 117 elements, which are of the type `std::vector<Node<T1,T2>*>`. I think you're getting ahead of yourself and need to study the fundamentals a bit more.

Comment: Do you want that your `std::vector<Node<T1,T2>*>` has `117` elements of the type `Node<T1,T2>*`? Or do you really want to have an array with `117` elements of the type `std::vector<Node<T1,T2>*>`?

Comment: @Visrut as I wrote in my answer use `std::array`.

Comment: Your implementation has more additional problems: The `Map` manages resources manually (`new`)  but has no destructor which leads to memory leaks, it has no copy constructor and copy assignment operator which could lead to double frees. If the instance of the map is copied.

Comment: @Visrut as written in my answer `std::array<Node<T1,T2>*, 117> hash_table;` is an array with `117` element of the type `<Node<T1,T2>*`.

Comment: If you assume that `T1` is always `string`, why do you even have `T1` as a template parameter?

Comment: And if `// i assumed that T1 is always string` why do you use a template parameter for that at all?

Comment: No, an `std::array` is not resizable, if you need that you would write `std::vector<Node<T1,T2>*> hash_table = std::vector<Node<T1,T2>*>(117);`.

Comment: It makes no difference whether it is a course or _" just"_ for questions, it is all about the time spent. If you have problems either ask the StackOverflow community (or any other online community), ask friends, teachers, … . And if none of this is an option you need to pay for it by asking a professional.

Comment: @t.niese ok , here I assumed that T1 is always string but how can I make hash function for other type like I can't type that if(T1 == int) than hash this what i do in this condition ?

Comment: That's not how a Q&A platform like StackOverflow works, if you have a new question, which this is, you need to create a new one instead of using the comment section of the current question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hash_table` (`std::vector<Node<T1,T2>*> hash_table[117];`) is a c style array, and does not have a method `size` as of that `table_size = hash_table.size();` results in the error:

```
error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘((Map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*)this)->Map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::hash_table’, which is of non-class type ‘std::vector<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*, std::allocator<Node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*> > [117]’
   21 |             table_size = hash_table.size();
```

And `hash_table[i] = nullptr;` won't work because `hash_table[i]` refers to an instance of `std::vector` and can't be `nullptr`

Instead of `std::vector<Node<T1,T2>*> hash_table[117];` you most likely want to have `std::array<Node<T1,T2>*, 117> hash_table;` or if you want to have a `std::vector` to be able to resize it you would use `std::vector<Node<T1,T2>*> hash_table = std::vector<Node<T1,T2>*>(117);`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
std::vector<Node<T1,T2>*> hash_table[117];
```

Is not a vector. It's an array of 117 vectors. Arrays don't have a `size()` member.